# R and looping across columns

Tags: r

I have "Sec1OSp", which looks like this:

```
TIMEBLOCK   ep.HRC_E    ep.HRC_D    ep.HRCcm_E  ep.HRCcm_D
   1           NA          NA          NA          NA
   2           NA          NA          NA          NA
   3           NA          NA          NA          NA
   4           NA          NA          NA          NA
   5           NA          NA          NA          NA
   6           NA          5           5           5
   7           NA          5           10          5
   8           NA          5           20          5
   9           NA          5           20          5 
   10          NA          10          20          10
   11          20          10          20          10
   12          20          10          20          10
   13          20          NA          20          10
   14          20          NA          20          10
   15          10          NA          10          10
   16          10          NA          10          5
   17          NA          NA          NA          NA
   18          NA          NA          NA          NA
   19          NA          NA          NA          NA
   20          NA          NA          NA          NA
   21          NA          NA          NA          NA
   22          NA          NA          NA          NA
   23          NA          NA          NA          NA
   24          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

I have "data.EP.S1p", which looks like this:

```
TIMEBLOCK   ep.HRC_E    ep.HRC_D    ep.HRCcm_E  ep.HRCcm_D
   1           NA          NA          NA          NA
   2           NA          NA          NA          NA
   3           NA          NA          NA          NA
   4           NA          NA          NA          NA
   5           NA          NA          NA          NA
   6           NA          NA          NA          NA
   7           NA          NA          NA          NA
   8           NA          NA          NA          NA
   9           NA          NA          NA          NA
   10          NA          NA          NA          NA
   11          20          NA          NA          NA
   12          20          NA          NA          NA
   13          20          NA          NA          NA
   14          20          NA          NA          NA
   15          10          NA          NA          NA
   16          10          NA          NA          NA
   17          NA          NA          NA          NA
   18          NA          NA          NA          NA
   19          NA          NA          NA          NA
   20          NA          NA          NA          NA
   21          NA          NA          NA          NA
   22          NA          NA          NA          NA
   23          NA          NA          NA          NA
   24          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

This code (below) currently uses the data from Sec1OSp$ep.HRC_E to fill data.EP.S1p$ep.HRC_E.

```
  for(t in 1:24) {
    Sec1OSpt <- subset(Sec1OSp, TIMEBLOCK==t)
    Sec1OSptnonNArows <- Sec1OSpt[!is.na(Sec1OSpt$ep.HRC_E),]
    if(nrow(Sec1OSptnonNArows) > 0) {
      if(sum(Sec1OSptnonNArows$ep.HRC_E, na.rm=TRUE) > 0) {
        data.EP.S1p$ep.HRC_E[t] <- (sum(Sec1OSptnonNArows$ep.HRC_E, na.rm=TRUE)) / nrow(Sec1OSptnonNArows)
      }
      else {
        data.EP.S1p$ep.HRC_E[t] <- NA
      }
    }
```

I would like be able to loop this code so that it is applied to all 4 columns, thereby using the 4 columns in Sec1OSp to fill the 4 columns in data.EP.S1p
Does anyone have a solution for me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is that really what your `Sec1OSp` looks like, where everything is `NA`?

Comment: Sorry, typo...that data is "data.EP.S1p" and I am using another data set called "Sec1OSp" to replace the NAs using the code above.
"Sec1OSp" headings match those of "data.EP.S1p".

Comment: To get good answers, you need to make a reproducible example. At the moment, we don't have any idea how your data works, or what exactly this code is meant to be achieving. At the very least, show how your data is now, and how you want it to look.

Comment: I've altered the question...does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly , you are first finding average values for 4 columns for each value of `TIMEBLOCK`. You can do that by using `aggregate` function. After that you can fill in those values in `data.EP.S1p` using `merge`

```
Sec1OSp <- read.table(textConnection("TIMEBLOCK   ep.HRC_E    ep.HRC_D    ep.HRCcm_E  ep.HRCcm_D\n1           NA          NA          NA          NA\n2           NA          NA          NA          NA\n3           NA          NA          NA          NA\n4           NA          NA          NA          NA\n5           NA          NA          NA          NA\n6           NA          5           5           5\n7           NA          5           10          5\n8           NA          5           20          5\n9           NA          5           20          5\n10          NA          10          20          10\n11          20          10          20          10\n12          20          10          20          10\n13          20          NA          20          10\n14          20          NA          20          10\n15          10          NA          10          10\n16          10          NA          10          5\n17          NA          NA          NA          NA\n18          NA          NA          NA          NA\n19          NA          NA          NA          NA\n20          NA          NA          NA          NA\n21          NA          NA          NA          NA\n22          NA          NA          NA          NA\n23          NA          NA          NA          NA\n24          NA          NA          NA          NA"), 
    header = TRUE)

data.EP.S1p <- read.table(textConnection("TIMEBLOCK   ep.HRC_E    ep.HRC_D    ep.HRCcm_E  ep.HRCcm_D\n1           NA          NA          NA          NA\n2           NA          NA          NA          NA\n3           NA          NA          NA          NA\n4           NA          NA          NA          NA\n5           NA          NA          NA          NA\n6           NA          NA          NA          NA\n7           NA          NA          NA          NA\n8           NA          NA          NA          NA\n9           NA          NA          NA          NA\n10          NA          NA          NA          NA\n11          20          NA          NA          NA\n12          20          NA          NA          NA\n13          20          NA          NA          NA\n14          20          NA          NA          NA\n15          10          NA          NA          NA\n16          10          NA          NA          NA\n17          NA          NA          NA          NA\n18          NA          NA          NA          NA\n19          NA          NA          NA          NA\n20          NA          NA          NA          NA\n21          NA          NA          NA          NA\n22          NA          NA          NA          NA\n23          NA          NA          NA          NA\n24          NA          NA          NA          NA"), 
    header = TRUE)


avgdata <- aggregate(Sec1OSp[, 2:5], by = list(Sec1OSp$TIMEBLOCK), FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
names(avgdata)[1] <- "TIMEBLOCK"
avgdata
##    TIMEBLOCK ep.HRC_E ep.HRC_D ep.HRCcm_E ep.HRCcm_D
## 1          1      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 2          2      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 3          3      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 4          4      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 5          5      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 6          6      NaN        5          5          5
## 7          7      NaN        5         10          5
## 8          8      NaN        5         20          5
## 9          9      NaN        5         20          5
## 10        10      NaN       10         20         10
## 11        11       20       10         20         10
## 12        12       20       10         20         10
## 13        13       20      NaN         20         10
## 14        14       20      NaN         20         10
## 15        15       10      NaN         10         10
## 16        16       10      NaN         10          5
## 17        17      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 18        18      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 19        19      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 20        20      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 21        21      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 22        22      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 23        23      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 24        24      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN

data.EP.S1p <- merge(data.EP.S1p[, "TIMEBLOCK", drop = FALSE], avgdata, all.x = TRUE)
data.EP.S1p
##    TIMEBLOCK ep.HRC_E ep.HRC_D ep.HRCcm_E ep.HRCcm_D
## 1          1      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 2          2      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 3          3      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 4          4      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 5          5      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 6          6      NaN        5          5          5
## 7          7      NaN        5         10          5
## 8          8      NaN        5         20          5
## 9          9      NaN        5         20          5
## 10        10      NaN       10         20         10
## 11        11       20       10         20         10
## 12        12       20       10         20         10
## 13        13       20      NaN         20         10
## 14        14       20      NaN         20         10
## 15        15       10      NaN         10         10
## 16        16       10      NaN         10          5
## 17        17      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 18        18      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 19        19      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 20        20      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 21        21      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 22        22      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 23        23      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
## 24        24      NaN      NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: `textConnection(` can be replaced with `text = ` when using `read.table`, to save a few keystrokes...